# CSS not showing

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is like this: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_navbar_horizontal_black_right, but it seems the code does not read the external CSS file. Here is the HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Runner To You</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../css/style.css">
</head>
<body>

<ul class="ul">
  <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
  <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Here is the CSS code:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

.active {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
}
```

Comment: make sure your file structre is set up correctly. do you get a 404 when you check in the dev tools? that means the link to your file is not correct.

Comment: `href="../../css/style.css"` is probably incorrect. What's your folder structure?

Comment: can you screenshot your chrome dev tools or similar thing

Comment: You may find this link helpful for understanding file paths https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

OR

Make CSS folder where your index.html present

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

Will solve the problem

Comment: Thank you, this fix it, but why I can not use the first one?

Comment: because of the incorrect path of the filename
../ works with the root directory 
you may be having a different file structure that's why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

I think you most likely have an issue with the directory hierarchy.

'..' is used to navigate the hierarchy of the file system. '.' is used for the current directory (this is often not used, as most commands will assume the current directory).

If these are used incorrectly, the files will not be found/executed hence your CSS is not being found.

Could you provide your file structure?

Answer (score 0):

if you are a newbie it's a good practice keeping all the HTML CSS and js files in the same folder so you can avoid all those lengthy path typing. you can just type the file and and file extension to access if its in the same folder